# Prevent a job, called in code, to overlap with job running in background in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, job-scheduling

In Laravel, I'm running a job in my code like this

```
Artisan::queue('mediaserver:process-queue', ['index' => $indexName]);
```

Same job is scheduled to run in background each hour. Sometimes I want to trigger it via my UI (so via Code) to fasten things up. What I need to prevent is, that the process starts while it always is running in background.

What is the best working method for this?

Comment: You're not going to be able to check the queue for the job. Instead, have a `running_jobs` table which gets a row inserted with some unique information, such as a column containing the job class. Listen for jobs being dispatched and have them create the row. When jobs are finished, have them delete the row. Check for the existence of the row before dispatcing the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's task scheduler handles overlapping jobs by [creating a temp file before the command runs, and destroying it after](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L229).

The name of the file is based on the cron schedule expression and command name.

[The existence of this file cause subsequent attempts to run the same command to be skipped](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L670-L672)

I would do something similar to this. At the top of your `mediaserver:process-queue` task I'd check if a temp file named something like `mediaserver__process_queue` existed in `storage/`. If it does, quit. If it doesn't create it. Destroy it when the task ends.

You would just have to be careful how you handle scenarios where the task quits unexpectedly from an uncaught exception, causing `mediaserver__process_queue` to remain even though the task is no longer running.